# Are there any established home workout routines for strength gains?

Tags: home-exercise

Most strength routines I've looked at focus on deadlift, squats, benchpress, all with parameteized volume and intensity ranges.

Things have changed due to covid.

Are there any established equivalent routines for a home workout? All I have is a resistance band and a broke bank account

Comment: There have been a [lot of home workout questions](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/search?q=home+workout) over the years. If you feel your question isn't covered by any of them, feel free to edit this into your question and it will be considered for re-opening.

Comment: Are you looking for powerlifting specific routines (since you're only getting SBD results)? If you are, there are quite a few youtubers that provide in depth explanations of many at home style alternatives (personal favs include megsquats and Jeff Nippard)